# Kendo MVC UI TreeList with multi-line text

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc, kendo-treelist

I added text-area as EditorTemplate (StringTextArea.cshtml) to TreeList.

```
@model string

@(Html.TextAreaFor(m => m, new { @class = "k-input k-textbox" }))
```

Model class

```
public class LevelViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LvlName { get; set; }
    [UIHint("StringTextArea")]
    public string LvlType { get; set; }
}
```

TreeList adds text-area in edit mode and I replace '\n' in LvlType to '`<br />`' before saving it to SQL Server 2008

```
LvlType = lvl.LvlType.Replace("\n", "<br />")
```

But it displays the string as it is, in the TreeList.

[image]

Is there any way to make the TreeList to display the string with line breaks?

Thanks

Comment: My guess is that the text get's encoded before it's presented, so I would replace "&lt;br /&gt;" with "<br />" when presenting in the treelist!

Comment: Thanks but it displays "Data1 &lt;br /&gt; Data2" not with line break

Comment: Don't replace what get's saved to the database, convert it before displaying it!

Comment: Strange! and you are replacing &lt;br /&gt; with <br /> not the other way around?, I'll have to set up a test project ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first idea to replace the encoded `<br />` was really making it more complicated than it has to be :(.

Best solution is to make a template: 
    template: "#=LvlType#"

When using # = # it will not encode, when using # : # it will encode!
My test: [Telerik dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/iJoWuqAJ)

```
<html>
<head>
<base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treelist/local-data-binding">
<style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />

<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="example">
        <div id="treelist"></div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var dataSource = new kendo.data.TreeListDataSource({
                    data: [
                      { id: 1, Name: "Daryl <br/>Sweeney", Position: "CEO", Phone: "(555) 924-9726", parentId: null },
                    ],

                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            id: "id",
                            expanded: true
                        }
                    }
                });

                $("#treelist").kendoTreeList({
                    dataSource: dataSource,
                    height: 540,
                    columns: [
                        { field: "Position" },
                        { field: "Name", template: "#=Name#" },
                        { field: "Phone" }
                    ]
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In DB it is stored as D1 <br /> D2 <br /> D3 and ....Template("#=LvlType#"), works. Thank you so much.

Comment: If you are using the Kendo UI MVC TreeList widget and want to hard code a column title to have a <br/> element in it, you can use the HeaderTemplate.  Let's say I want to have the title be "Something<br />about<br />nothing" I would add .HeaderTemplate("Something<br />about<br />nothing") to the column definition.